# How to restrict special characters at the start or end in string using regex pattern?

Tags: regex, validation

I need to create a regex pattern with following conditions-

1. It can have %[percentage], / [Front slash], \ [Back Slash], ( ) [Brackets], ™ [Trademark], +[plus], – [ hyphen], : [colon]. It can be combination of words, special characters and numbers.
2. It can allow words like **check-in** but **- :** or **-% :** should not be allowed, basically if someone tries to write something which starts with special characters, it should not be allowed, but mentioned characters can come in between.
3. Also two special characters cannot come together in between string.
4. It can also allow white spaces between start, middle and end of string.
5. It can also accept a single character.

I have created one which does not allow other special characters except the ones mentioned and also white spaces. How do I allow mentioned characters in between and not at the start. Below is what I wrote:

```
var string='Incharge';
var a= RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-:%/\\()\u2122.+\s]+$/).test(string);
console.log(a);
```

My Requirement:

```
string='In-charge' -> Correct
string='Incharge' -> Correct
string='In charge' -> Correct
string='-In-charge' -> In Correct
string='--In-charge' -> In Correct
string='  In-charge' -> Correct
string=' a' -> Correct
string='in-charge' -> Correct
string='in-:charge' -> In Correct
string=' in-  ' -> Correct
string='in@charge' -> In Correct
```

I tried to fit in all the conditions but was unable to do it. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You don't have to abuse tags.

Comment: Java and javascript have no relationship. Please choose one.

Comment: Hi, apologize for the mistake. Removed the wrong tags.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more detailed and relevant. How would I know if it will be allowed for answers and not closed? Can someone help me here?

Comment: "In-char%ge" should also be correct?

Comment: Yes. there can be multiple special characters but no two special characters can be together.

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+(?:[%\/\\()\u2122+\-:][A-Za-z0-9 ]+)*$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzYNoB/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?:[-:%/\\()\u2122.+][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)*$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/KfIx3A/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9\s]+           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-:%/\\()\u2122.+]       any character of: '-', ':', '%', '/',
                             '\\', '(', ')', 'TM', '.', '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9\s]+           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9', whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                             \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

JavaScript:

```js
const valid_strings = ['In-charge','Incharge','In charge','  In-charge',' a','in-charge',' in-  '];
const invalid_strings = ['-In-charge','--In-charge','in-:charge','in@charge '];
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?:[-:%/\\()\u2122.+][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)*$/;
valid_strings.forEach(x => console.log(x, '(must be true) =>', regex.test(x)));
invalid_strings.forEach(x => console.log(x, '(must be false) =>', regex.test(x)));
```